# How to load first row ng-click in ng-repeat div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem to load first data from div ng-repeat before click ng-repeat. The code will be like this:

```
<div class"profile" ng-repeat="data in information" ng-click="getData(data.id)">
    <div class="profile-name">{{data.name}}</div>
</div>

<div class="profileDetail" ng-repeat="data in informationDetail">
    <div>Age: {{age}}</div>
    <div>Gender: {{gender}}</div>
</div>
```

For now the div `class="profileDetail"` display only work when click the div `class="profile"` but i want to display default load from first row ng-repeat in div `class="profile"` based on id and display on `class="profileDetail"` before click on the div. Hope someone can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set informationDetail default state in onInit in component.ts
Something like this:

```
public ngOnInit(): void { 
  informationDetail = { id: 123 }
}
```